# Terminal text space not fully utilized ( ng-terminal && xterm.js )

Tags: angular, xtermjs

I have build an terminal, inside the angular application using the ng-terminal (based on xterm.js). But while writing the text inside the terminal, it does not go beyond certain width (see pic.).
We are using the websocket for connection with backend and displaying the response in terminal.write() method. I have only changed the default look of the ng-terminal(like font,size and background color etc.) , beside that everything is default configuration.

windows 11
"ng-terminal": "^6.0.0-beta",
Angular 14[image]

I am expecting the terminal text to adjust according to browser window's height and width.

A similar type of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009938/xterm-js-fitaddon-max-width-textarea-line-wrapping)

Comment: A terminal and all related OS interfaces (TTY/PTY, termios) maintain a size, which typically defaults to 80x25 characters for many libs dealing with terminal stuff. To support different terminal sizes/resizing you need to announce size changes back to the OS/PTY. How you do that depends on your PTY lib.